# Setting up iPhone sdk on Linux?

Tags: iphone, linux, sdk, set

My iPod touch is jailbroken and I have looked for days to locate a comprehendable guide I am downloading the official sdk from apple as I type but I need to know how to set up the unofficial toolchain I have experience coding c/c++ and am learning objective c which is equally compared to c++ I just need some help setting the enviroment up I would be eternally grateful for any help. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try looking over [saurik's guide](http://www.saurik.com/id/4).

Comment: This is for very old OS & will not work for latest iOS 4.x. Try http://www.xmlvm.org/ also. As it supports iPhone coding in Java & Java is platform invariant. Thus, you can programming for iPhone from Linux. (However, I am not sure it supports latest iOS 4.x or not)